# Spring batch guide source - about generic setting

Tags: java

I have a look into a Spring-batch sample source in spring.io - Creating Batch Servie.

In the example, there is a code like below

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

What I want to know is "{{". Is that java standard code? 
And how can I call it? I wanted to google it but don't know what I have to search...

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider simplified part of the text

```
   = new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
    {
        setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
    }
    });
```

The code means we extend DelimitedLineTokenizer introducing anonymous inner class and with inner block of { } we just invoke setNames() method with predefined array.

We can do the same this way

```
   DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer= new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
   tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
```